# Translate IFC Failure

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I try to translate a IFC file by API, but failed.

And I can translate this file successful in [https://viewer.autodesk.com/designviews].

The manifest

```
{
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czp......",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "name": "XXXXXXXX.ifc",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf",
            "status": "failed"
        }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "failed"
}
```

Comment: Could you consider providing the full-length URN and a non-confidential reproducible IFC model demonstrating this issue to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`? Need to do some investigation on the model

Comment: Thank you very much. We try to create a new version IFC, and it can be translate successful. But we do not know why the first one only can be translated at View Online. If it happen again We will ask your help.  Thank you for  your assistance.